# How to select element with specific ID before / after current element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, selector

I have a website that contains multiple DIVs with the same element that are not organised...

For example:

```
<div>
   <div id='abc_152142'>
   </div>
   <div id='abc_2353253'>
   </div>
   <div id='abc_3421121'>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div id='abc_44211241'>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div id='abc_541221421'>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div id='abc_654354'> // --> THIS ONE IS SELECTED
   </div>
   <div id='abc_754335'>
   </div>
   <div id='abc_845345'>
   </div>
</div>
```

So as written in code I am on id 'abc_654354' and want to get to element with the same ID beginning before and after current element.

I have tried:

```
$(this).prev("div[id^='td_']");
$(this).next("div[id^='td_']");
```

and that did not get me any results...

IDs are random and the only thing that they have in common is the beginning of ID (in this example i used `td_`).

Thank you for help!

Comment: Provide the context for `this`? Some handler?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are your ids prefixed by `td_` or by `abc_`?

Comment: and get element by same id? there can only be 1 id in the html, use classes instead?

Comment: The question is beginning with same id and its valid code @themosquitokiller

Comment: Huh sorry ... 'td_' ... There are unique IDs - td_<unique_id>...

Comment: So what is `this` ???

Comment: @M.V. is it a on click attached to div?

Comment: I have on mousedown element ... but anyway ... id does not matter ... I can just do the selector $("#abc_654354")... and that go to previous and next element

Comment: @M.V. you want to get an element having an id beginning with `abc_654354---` when you select div with id = `abc_654354` ?

Comment: I am just wondering if this is possible ... we can go with classes ... I have element with mouse click selected with class XY ... and all I want to do is to get previous and next element with the same class no matter what the HTML structure is like.

Comment: If I just go with next I get result ... but for previous it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select the elements based on their indexes in the jQuery collection:

```
var $e = $('div[id^="td_"]');
var i = $e.index(this);

var $before = $e.eq(i - 1);
var $after = $e.eq(i + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QGsza/

Comment: Yes thanks ... the solution could be to work with indexes... But I always get -1 as result of $e.index(this)

Comment: @M.V. This mean the `$e` collection doesn't include the `this` element, make sure the selector is correct, I have added a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks man! I figure it out! Now it works ... All I did is make a call to this ID again and it works! Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior here for previous:

```
<div>
   <div id='abc_541221421'>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div id='abc_654354'> // --> THIS ONE IS SELECTED
   </div>
   <div id='abc_754335'>
   </div>
   <div id='abc_845345'>
   </div>
</div>
```

is that `<div id='abc_541221421'>` gets returned then:

```
function getPrevious(){    
    var previous = $(this).prev("div[id^='abc_']");
    if (previous.length > 0)
      return previous;
    return $(this).parent().prev().find("div[id^='abc_']:last")
}
```

and for next:

```
function getNext(){    
    var next = $(this).next("div[id^='abc_']");
    if (next.length > 0)
      return next;
    return $(this).parent().next().find("div[id^='abc_']:first")
}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/3K6Cj/) the fiddle.

Comment: This could also work ... But as I have said code is really unorganized and in can not be sure that this structure is always valid! But thanks for suggest anyhow!